# Pass argument to react method correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arguments

By means of react I am trying through a click to modify a parameter of a state.

```
<button onClick={this.switchFase(1)} >Origin</button>

switchFase= (num_proces)=>{
  this.setState({ process: num_proces });
}
```

I understand that it is not the correct way to do it, can someone explain to me what I am doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish here? You want to update a state value when a button is clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass a funciton to onClick, instead you are calling `this.switchFase(1)` immediately and passing its result (`undefined`) to onClick. Try this:

```
<button onClick={()=>this.switchFase(1)} >Origin</button>

switchFase= (num_proces)=>{
  this.setState({ process: num_proces });
}
```

https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html#passing-arguments-to-event-handlers